# Framing a glass greenhouse

Tags: concrete, framing, steel, glass, engineering

I would like to build a greenhouse using an existing steel frame structure that is already erected.  It is 20L X 20W X 10H.  I have many large sheets of 1/8" tempered glass to use for this.  Will this glass be acceptable for use provided the structure is properly framed?  Any advice on the structure and weight would be helpful.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: How big are your sheets of glass?

Comment: Weight of what?

Comment: Hi Aloysius.  My glass sheets are 77.75 x 39.25 x .125 thick.

Comment: Hi FreeMan.  I guess I'm just concerned about all the weight of glass and framing.  Should be no problem as long as my foundation and knee wall is solid, yes